# Setup Method with object type parameter using MOQ

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I have an interface

```
public interface IProgramer
{
    bool ReturnStatus(Program prg,string filepath);
}
```

Class

```
public class Programer :IProgramer
{
    public bool ReturnStatus(Program prg,string filepath)
    {
       // logic
       return status
    }
}
```

Unit Testcase

```
public void StartOperationTest()
{
    string dummyfilepath = "C://Users//x//";
    Program dummyprgObj = new Program
    {
       Name = "x",
       Rollno = 1,
     
    };
    var mock = new Mock<IProgramer>();
    mock.Setup(x => x.ReturnStatus(dummyprgObj, dummyfilepath)).Returns(true);
}
```

setup method is always giving false.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: that was a prototype of it, class Programer : IProgrammer is their in actual code. are you seeing any issue in setup?

Comment: Could you post the real test method implementation?

Comment: The test method is incomplete. Where do you use `mock` object (there is setup only, but no usage)?

Comment: After setup, i have called:

mock.Object.ReturnStatus(dummyprgObj,dummyfilepath)
I am always getting false.

Comment: Your setup works fine - https://snipboard.io/AIKgVk.jpg. I always get `true`.

Comment: Can you please share with us the Act and Assert part of your test as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try using mock.SetupGet() instead of 'setup' you are using.
and also one observation, the class 'Programer' should implement interface 'IProgramer'

Comment: `SetupGet` is for mocking a property (`get`), not a method

Comment: any idea why setup method is returning false ?

Comment: @tyu, please, post the full test method implementation.

Comment: public void StartOperationTest()
        {
          string dummyfilepath = "C://Users//x//";
           Programer dummyprgObj = new dummyprgObj
           {
               Name = "x",
               Rollno = 1,
             
           };
            var mock  = new Mock<IProgramer>();
            mock.Setup(x => x.ReturnStatus(dummyprgObj, dummyfilepath)).Returns(true);
           
   }

Comment: @tyu, just edit your question and post this method in question with code formatting.